# Passing arguments to event handlers in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I've been trying to learn React and came across this piece of code.

```js
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

This baffles me. How can deleteRow have two arguments? It is only supposed to have one. What does putting the 'e' into it do and why is it needed? Why is id the first argument in the first line but the second argument in the second line? Why do we need to use 'bind' or 'this.' with deleteRow at all? I thought it was a built-in function.

Comment: *"I thought it was a built-in function."* - It isn't.  It's defined somewhere in the React component you're looking at.  Find the function definition to see what its arguments are and what it does with them.

Comment: You are asking a lot of different questions at once. Consider editing your question so it asks only one, or it might be closed

Comment: If it isn't a built-in function, why is it listed here? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp

Comment: @Urthona26: As an aside, [use a better reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow).  W3Schools is notoriously awful.  But more to the point, it does appear that you've found a (somewhat obscure) built-in method which shares the same name as the one shown here.  There's nothing stopping a developer from re-using an existing name.  But is that the method being invoked here?  What is `this` in the context of this code?  Is it an `HTMLTableElement` or a React component?  The question implies the latter.  But only you can find out for certain.

Comment: @David I'm surprised to hear that a developer can re-use an existing name. How would the computer know the difference between the built-in method and the user-defined method if the same name is used? Surely I couldn't, for example, define my own method called pop() or push() when these are already taken?

Comment: @Urthona26: Try it and find out.  The name used also depends on the context.  In this case `deleteRow` is a function on a specific object.  If you create a function called `deleteRow` on another object then the two have nothing to do with one another.  The parser would look for that identifier *on that object*, not *anywhere in the language specification or any other defined object*.  And even when a specific name is already in the current scope, you can still "shadow" it by defining something new in the current scope with the same name.  There's nothing wrong with any of this.

Comment: The thing that might be confusing me is javascript's dot notation. I can understand that deleteRow() refers to the global deleteRow function and X.deleteRow refers to the deleteRow function created in object X, but this isn't always what the dot notation means. For example, if X is an array, X.push() doesn't mean 'the push function defined in array X', it means 'apply the push function to array X'.

Comment: @Urthona26 Did you try out an answer? Consider giving some feedback

Comment: @atxck I gave up, I'm afraid. There are just so many things about that particular piece of code that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

`e` is the event that is passed to the handler, but you can also pass other parameters.

```js
// handlers
const deleteRow = (e, someVal) => {
   console.log(e);
   console.log(someVal); // "another value"
}

const deleteRow = (e) => {
   console.log(e); // still get the event
}

<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(e, "another value")}>Delete Row</button>

// if you don't need to pass other arguments, you can even do
<button onClick={this.deleteRowB}>Delete Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be misleading

The onClick would pass the event automatically if you don't specify

```
const deleteItem = (event) => {
     console.log(event)
}
<button onClick={deleteItem}>Delete Item</button>
```